# Can we have more than one core domain, as the result of Distillation process

Tags: domain-driven-design

Can we have more than one core domain, as the result of Distillation process (ref. DDD green book, Chapter 15, "Core Domain", by Eric Evans)?

As far as I could read, there is only one "core domain".
Other domains are categorized as, such as sub domains, highlighted (core) domains...

Notes:
I've read the following discussion but I think they doesn't answer my question.

[DDD, identifying the core domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274226/ddd-identifying-the-core-domain)
[Can Core Domain span multiple Bounded Contexts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345546/can-core-domain-span-multiple-bounded-contexts)

The book: Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine a single core domain would be best for future maintainability.  Having 2 cores would cause confusion for anyone reading the code.

If you have a one group of things that are core and another group of things that are also core, maybe you could organise them in your single core domain using namespaces?

Comment: Thank you. As far as I read and understand the DDD book by Eric Evans, this is what Erics recommends. He uses "core domain", not "core domains".